# How do I link SDL3 if I am building it as part of my project?

Tags: cmake, sdl

I can't seem to get the 3rd party library SDL to link to my main application file.  I'm new to this and it could be that I'm missing the point, or my project structure is not standard, but the answer is eluding me.  How do I link SDL if I am building it as part of my project?

The project structure is as follows:

```
-App_Name
 -libs
  -sdl <third party library with cmake>
   -<sources downloaded from [libsdl.org](https://www.libsdl.org/)
  -CMakeLists.txt
 -src
  -main.cpp
  -CMakeLists.txt
 -CMakeLists.txt
```

Contents of the files

App_Name/libs/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(sdl)
```

App_Name/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SDL_INCLUDES "../libs/sdl/include")
set(SDL_BINARY ../libs/sdl/sdl3.lib)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES *.cpp)

add_executable(app ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(app SYSTEM PRIVATE ${SDL_INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(app SDL3)
```

App_Name/src/main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
// #include"SDL3/SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "hello world working" << std::endl;

    // if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
    //     std::cout << "Error initializing SDL\n" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    // }

    // SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("Ford Galaxie Dash", 1240, 400, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
  
    return 0;
}
```

App_Name/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(cmakefun VERSION 0.1.0 DESCRIPTION "Testing SDL" LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(libs)
```

Answer (score 1):

At least [according to the docs](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-cmake.md#including-sdl-in-your-project), when using a vendored SDL, you `add_subdirectory` the vendored SDL directory (the one containing SDL's root CMakeLists.txt file), and then `target_link_libraries` to `SDL3::SDL3`.

Try changing your `target_link_libraries(app SDL3)` to `target_link_libraries(app SDL3::SDL3)`.